# How vulnerable is this server side form validation?

Tags: php, security

I recently wrote this bit of code to validate some forms. As a student developer I might have missed out on security issues.

The script checks required, email, alpha & numeric fields.
I have not yet added any sort of captcha which I might add soon enough.

How much damage can a malicious user do with such server side code. (with/without captca)

```
<?php

    # post data collection
    $name   = "John Doe";
    $email  = "a@b.c";
    $age    = "193";
    $x      = "s";
    $y      = "s";

    # select data that needs validation
    $validate   = array(
        'required'      => array($name, $email, $x, $y),
        'validEmail'    => array($email),
        'validNumber'   => array($age),
        'validAlpha'    => array($name)
    );

    # error messages
    $errorsMsgs = array(
        'required'      => 'Please fill out all required fields.',
        'validEmail'    => 'is an invalid email address.',
        'validNumber'   => 'is an invalid number.',
        'validAlpha'    => 'contains invalid characters. This field only accepts letters and spaces.'
    );

    $errorMarkup    = "<h1>We found a few errors :-(</h1><h2>Please fix these errors and try again</h2><ol>";
    $successMarkup  = "<h1>Success!</h1><h2>Your form was sent successfully.</h2>";
    $backMarkup     = "<a href=\"" . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "\">Back to form</a>";

    # begin state
    $valid = true;

    # loop through fields of error types
    foreach ($validate as $type => $fields) {
        # loop through values of fields to be tested
        foreach ($fields as $value) {
            # throw error if value is required and not entered
            if ($type === 'required' && strlen($value) === 0) {
                $errorMarkup .= "<li>$errorsMsgs[$type]</li>";
                $valid = false;
                break;
            }
            else if (
                        $type === 'validEmail'  && !filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ||
                        $type === 'validNumber' && !preg_match('/^[0-9 ]+$/', $value) ||
                        $type === 'validAlpha'  && !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/', $value)
                    ) {
                if (strlen($value) === 0) {break;} # skip check if value is not entered
                $errorMarkup .= "<li>\"$value\" $errorsMsgs[$type]</li>";
                $valid = false;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($valid) {
        # email form
        $body = $successMarkup . $backMarkup;
        $title = "Form sent";
    } else {
        $body = $errorMarkup . "</ol>" . $backMarkup;
        $title = "Form errors";
    }

    # write html ouput
    echo "<!DOCTYPE html><head><title>$title</title><style type=\"text/css\">body{margin:100px;font:16px/1.5 sans-serif;color:#111}h1{font-size:32px;margin:0;font-weight:bold}h2{font-size:18px;margin:0 0 20px 0}ol,li{list-style-position:inside;padding-left:0;margin-left:0}</style></head><body>$body</body></html>";
?>
```

UPDATE:
This is a simple email form. It basically validates the data for invalid input and emails it to the website owner. I have added the bit that emails the form below:

```
if ($valid) {
    $formcontent = "Full Name: $full_name \nEmail Address: $email_address \nLikability: $likability \nCountry: $country \nMessage: $message \nSend me your lousy newsletter: $send_me_your_lousy_newsletter \n";
    $formcontent = wordwrap($formcontent, 70, "\n", true);
    $recipient = "a@b.c"; $subject = "Contact Form"; $mailheader = "From: $email_address \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);

    $body = $successMarkup . $backMarkup;
    $title = "Form sent";
}
```

Comment: Vulnerable to what? For example your regular expression is not charset encoding aware at some point.

Comment: @hakre Dude, there are like 3 vulnerabilities in this code. What do you mean `"Vulnerable to what?"` he means vulnerable to *vulnerabilities*.

Comment: @Rook: Can you be more specific? You're turning a verb into a noun, which does not add any more insight. For example, I already highlighted encoding problems, but I dunno if kht is looking for those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** There are at-least 2 xss vulnerabilities in your application so you **need** [to read up on XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

```
$errorMarkup .= "<li>\"$value\" $errorsMsgs[$type]</li>";
```

and

```
 $backMarkup     = "<a href=\"" . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "\">Back to form</a>";
```

(The attacker can exploit this using a redirect from a URL that contains JavaScript,  however browsers should urlencode the referer url which will mitigate this issue.)

You should use this function to sanitize:

```
htmlspecialchars($var,ENT_QUOTES);
```

**2.** Its not clear if this is vulnerable to CRLF injection.  If its value is passed though `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` then you should be fine:

```
$mailheader = "From: $email_address \r\n"
```

**3.** Also this form is [vulnerable to CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29).  And some might say that the attacker doesn't really care.  Using CSRF an attacker could create a storm of email,  and bomb the inbox of `johndoe@gmail.com`.  If it was vulnerable to CRLF injection I would be more concerned.

Adding a captcha would prevent CSRF and prevent automation as a whole.

Comment: @hakre  write a PoC then I'll care.

Comment: Is in your answer: `htmlspecialchars($var,ENT_QUOTES);` - if `$var` is UTF-7 encoded, htmlspecialchars will not do anything useful.

Comment: @hakre 2 problems with that.  1) The content-type must be set to UTF-7.  2)They must be using IE,  no other browser supports UTF-7.   UTF-7 is an encoding standard for SMTP not HTTP,  no web server is going to set the content-type to UTF-7 so this is not a vulnerability.

Comment: Sure it is, many users are using IE btw. And server won't care as long as the HTTP request message is passable.

Comment: @hakre  This is **100% impossible to exploit** under IE.  IE no longer performs content sniffing when the content-type is absent.  Maybe you should **TRY IT** to avoid entrancement.  And if it works, then you should try and obtain a CVE.

Comment: It's one thing to dislike the pre-conditions that could be, and another to accept that the code is not charset independent. If you don't see the point, I can't help you. This is not related specifically to IE sniffing anyway. And no need to file a CVE, `htmlspecialchars` has a charset parameter.

Comment: @hakre  yes it has a charset parameter, and its not vulnerable if you don't use it.   However,  without it it can damage multi-byte characters,  like the ones found in utf-8.

Comment: I'm not sure if the second xss vulnerability is actually exploitable in practice. But even if it isn't exploitable, it should still be sent through `htmlspecialchars`

Comment: @hakre since any sane person uses UTF-8 nowadays I usually don't care about charset.

Comment: @CodeInChaos It looks like its urlencoded,  so its not exploitable.  It would have been exploitable,  you just have to forward the victim to the page from a page with the name of your XSS payload.

Comment: @Rook I'm not sure if it's url encoded with all browsers under all circumstances. So personally I'd still encode it for good style and peace of mind, even if I couldn't find a concrete vulnerability.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is vulnerable to html-injection.

```
"<li>\"$value\" $errorsMsgs[$type]</li>"
```

Outputs user data without encoding characters with special meaning in html, in particular `<>"'`.

Which in turn leads to cross-site-scripting problems.

That happens by outputting `$value`. So you should encode dangerous characters with `htmlspecialchars`:

```
"<li>\"".htmlspecialchars($value)."\" $errorsMsgs[$type]</li>"
```

*(If you use a strange charset you need to specify the charset as parameter to `htmlspecialchars`. But with common charsets such as UTF-8 and most single byte ANSI charsets this is not required)*

Comment: ...and the solution for that among others is `htmlentities` http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: I prefer `htmlspecialchars`. If you specified an encoding(which should be UTF-8) there is no need to encode all characters.

Comment: If I changed those bits to this: "&lt;li&gt;"\"$value\" $errorsMsgs[$type]&lt;/li&gt;" - would it be safer? What else should I be doing to avoid XSS?

Comment: I have added this to the start of the script, would it fix the XSS issue? $post_data = filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS );

Comment: No idea if it would avoid the problem, but in any case it's the wrong way to do it. Html output should be escaped at output time. Just like SQL should be escaped when you build the statement and not earlier [Or even better use parameterized queries]

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming for this answer that you are saving the form fields to a MySQL database since you don't specify what happens after form validation.  If that's not the case, please update your question appropriately.

I don't see the code that implements email validation.  There's potential for SQL injection if you allow certain characters through as part of an email address.

Generally for PHP and MySQL , I would start with [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to escape dangerous characters that could otherwise cause unintended behavior (SQL Injection) in the database, no matter what input validation was previously done (what happens if you change the input validation later to allow e.g. an apostrophe in the name because `Amy's Cafe` wants to sign up...).

As for [Captcha](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2008/aug/28/internet.captcha), it has been broken for many years.  While it offers some protection against simple bots, serious bots just figure out what to input automatically.

Comment: Input data validation isn't the place to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Agree 100%... did that not come across in my answer?

Comment: Just a note, it doesn't strip chars, but escapes with backslash. Meaning "Amy's Cafe" will become "Amy\'s Cafe" and not "Amys Cafe".

Comment: You are also talking about simple captcha's... http://www.google.com/recaptcha broken?

Comment: *mysql_real_escape_string to strip dangerous characters out of any data going to the database* This is not what `mysql_real_escape_string()` does, and it's not only used for security either.

Comment: None of the data will be saved to a database, its an email form so it will simply be emailed to the form owner.

Comment: Updated that mysql_real_escape_string escapes (thus the name :-) characters and does not strip them.  That's what I get for getting on SO before the first cup of coffee :-)